# How to disable version control for new projects in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea, version-control

When creating a new project in IntelliJ, version control is enabled by default and uses the IdeaProjects directory.

[image: Settings]

None of the version control settings seem to matter:

- It would seem that when there are no mappings in *File – Other Settings – Settings for New Projects... – Version Control*, that there should not be any when creating a new project either.
- It seems to be the default behavior, as restoring the default IDE settings does not change this either.

Is there a way to disable version control altogether for new projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete hidden **.git** directory placed in the root of project.
Or you can easily disable version control by removing vcs content roots settings in **File | Settings | Version Control** or you can turn off vcs plugins at all in **FIle | Settings | Plugins**.

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing such behavior since you have an initialized git repository in IdeaProjects folder (so it's not a version control for new project but rather version control for the whole IdeaProjects folder). 
In order to fix it, you need to delete .git directory from IdeaProjects folder and mapping will not be detected in newly created projects.